# ¿What can I tweak in Optapplaner solver configuration to select this move?

Tags: java, solver, optaplanner, heuristics

I am running an heuristics construction for a problem in Optaplanner.

This is how initializing variables is set. Which I donnot really understand since all my planning entities start off from null. Since that is the case hard level is always going to be 0 at the beggining and soft level is always gonna have negative values. As the variables are assigned I would like the soft level to increase (until 0)

```
<initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN/ONLY_UP</initializingScoreTrend>
```

This is the trace of what the solver is doing:
I would rather it chose the move with index 1 instead of the move with index 0. ¿How could I tweak the solver configuration or the rules from the ScoreDirector to have it choose the first?

```
06:53:30.895 [markThread-2] DEBUG     CH step (4075), time spent (162264), score ([0]hard/[-4669100]soft), selected move count (6), picked move (G 169 B {null -> null}).
06:53:30.895 [markThread-1] TRACE         Move index (1), score ([0]hard/[-4590500]soft), move (G 213 A {null -> C1 }).
06:53:30.896 [markThread-2] TRACE         Move index (0), score ([0]hard/[-4669100]soft), move (G 169 B {null -> null}).
06:53:30.902 [markThread-1] TRACE         Move index (2), score ([-6]hard/[-4590500]soft), move (G 213 A {null -> C2 }).
```

Answer (score 0):

- Either don't use `nullable=true`
- or add a medium constraint to penalize all `null` assignments (see docs **overconstrained planning**).